# Is there a ninth fold to the Eightfold path or is it just eight?

Tags: eightfold-path

For the longest time, I never had much to question about it but I've taken to wondering about an extra one, one that wasn't there before. I get to feeling that "right spirit" should be another fold. Can Buddha's spirit be tested for this?

Answer (score 8):

There is the:

- 8 Fold Path is the practice up to Sotapanna, and
- 10 Fold Path for full enlightenment

The Noble 8 Fold Path is the practice up to Sotapanna.

[image]

Source: [Maha Cattarīsaka Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/6.10-Maha-Cattarisaka-S-m117-piya.pdf) intorduction

To go beyond Sotapanna one must add 2 more elements under liberation/release which are:

- right knowledge
- right freedom

[image]

[Maha Cattarīsaka Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/6.10-Maha-Cattarisaka-S-m117-piya.pdf)

Comment: Good post-Suminda. I thought that the right knowledge and right release for Arahants.

Comment: Yes. It is for arahants.

Answer (score 0):

> Just as the ocean has one taste, the taste of salt, even so, this teaching and training has one taste too, the taste of liberation.

This taste of liberation is the taste of dispassion. The taste of dispassion is the taste of non-clinging.

Non-clinging is not clinging to the past, not clinging to the future, not clinging to the present.

Not clinging means not denying the reality, not denying the truth.

Not denying the truth, means being willing to know the truth, handle the truth, and live with the truth.

To know the truth one must look for truth.

To look for truth one must be unsatisfied with half-truths.

To be unsatisfied with half-truths one must see that half-truths are *dukkha*.

To see half-truths as dukkha, one must have something to compare with, a basis for comparison. One must have glimpsed or have been shown that "everything is right" is *sukha*.

To understand that "right" is "sukha" one must have the right notion of "right" and "wrong".

Having the right notion of Right and Wrong is called The Right View.

So the spirit of Buddhism is The Right View, nothing else missing.